# adding angular files to Express-node application

Tags: express, angular

Created an express app using visual studio 2015. Default settings. Created a basic angular app and run the html in chrome as a test and it worked (displayed Hello World) as expected. 
Now when I add the angular files to the express app and use a default route with a res (sendfile(index.html)) and suddenly it doesn't display the angular app.

It should load the html file, which is referencing the angular cdn link and yet it doesn't show the angular output. Is it how I reference my angular cdn or something else I'm missing here?

```
enter `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<app>loading...</app>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-  
  polyfills.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.umd.min.js">

</script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-
all.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

My Angular file app.js

```
`var App = ng.core.Component({
selector: "app",
template: '<h1>Hello{{target}}!</h1>'
})
.Class({
constructor: function () {
    this.target = 'World';
}
});
ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(App);` code here
```

This is my index.js in express with the get route pointing to the index.html in the res.sendfile()

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile('./app/index.html');
//res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

module.exports = router;
Run it in a browser and the angular app will run. Add those two simple files to a folder in express and reference the index.html file in a get res.sendfile(index.html) and you get the 'loading...' which means angular is working?

Comment: I updated your tags, because Angular2 is not the same framework as Angularjs (aside from them sharing a part of their name).

Comment: also, I don't know much about Angular2, but I'm pretty sure that 2.0.0-beta.9 is a really old beta version;  The current release is 2.2.2

Comment: What is the error message in the console?

Comment: Hi, Claies: what do you mean updated the tags? Did you get it to work in your local env? The angular tags work fine when I run index.html in Chrome without express. So the reference is not outdated.

Comment: Hi ppovoski: No error in the console. It just logs the get req

Comment: The issue is angular is not displaying the hello world. It displays "Loading..." from the html page. So express is working fine. loading and displaying the html file correctly. It is angular that is not displaying it is part which led me to believe it's the angular reference tags.

Comment: Should I add the angular packages to the node-module folder?